# Django: class-view lacking attribute COOKIES

Tags: python, django, backbone.js, cookies

I am currently playing around with REST and backbone.js and ran into this issue:

```
'LoginView' object has no attribute 'COOKIES'
```

Here comes the following code for might have caused the problem. I have commented out a few things in the javascript, since I wanted it to load directly to the server instead, but I thought it would be just as good to bring it along.

I can also add that I have checked for the csrf-token in the form and it is there.

views.py

```
class LoginView(TemplateView):
    authentication_form=LoginForm
    form_class = LoginForm
    redirect_field_name=REDIRECT_FIELD_NAME
    template_name = 'front/login.html'
    initial = {'key': 'value'}

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.form_class(initial=self.initial)
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})

    @method_decorator(sensitive_post_parameters())
    @csrf_protect
    @never_cache
    @api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.form_class(request.POST)
        print request.COOKIES('csrftoken')
        print request.POST.get('csrfmiddlewaretoken')
        if form.is_valid():
            #if not is_safe_url(url=redirect_to, host=request.get_host()):
            #   redirect_to = resolve_url(settings.LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL)
            print request.POST.get('email')
            #user = self.get_user(request.POST.get('email'))
            #print user
            #auth = UserDataAuthentication(request, user)
            user = authenticate(email=request.POST.get('email'), password=request.POST.get('password'))
            if user is not None:
                auth_login(request, user)
                return Response(user, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/login/')
```

login.js

```
var csrftoken = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');
SigninView = Backbone.View.extend({
    events: {
        //"click button[type=submit]": "sendRequest"
    },
    sendRequest: function( event ){
        //event.preventDefault();
        var csrftoken = $.cookie('csrftoken');
        var url = '/login/validate/';
        var email = $("#id_email").val();
        var password = $("#id_password").val();
        var items = {
                        email: email,
                        password: password,
                        csrfmiddlewaretoken: csrftoken
                    };      
        console.log(csrftoken);
        $.ajax({
            url:url,
            type:'POST',
            dataType:"json",
            data: items,
            success: function (data) {  
                var json = $.parseJSON(data);
                console.log(data);
            },
            error: function (xhr, textStatus, error) {
                $("#form_error").css('padding','7px').css('border-radius','4px').html('Error recieved: ' + error).fadeIn();
                console.log("Status: "+textStatus);
                console.log("Type: "+error);
            }
        });
    }
});
var signin_view = new SigninView({
    el: $("#login_form")
});
```

We are two people working on this, I have taken upon myself to work with Python, while my friend takes care of the js-part. I have yet to experience enough of Django to actually find what might have caused an error to arise due to cookies. I try, most of the time, to stay away from cookies, if I can, but it seems difficult here.

And of course: The traceback:

```
Traceback:
File "/home/ryuu/Programming/Python/tabr/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  114.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/home/ryuu/Programming/Python/tabr/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in view
  69.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/ryuu/Programming/Python/tabr/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in dispatch
  87.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/ryuu/Programming/Python/tabr/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapper
  29.             return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/ryuu/Programming/Python/tabr/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/debug.py" in sensitive_post_parameters_wrapper
  75.             return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/ryuu/Programming/Python/tabr/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in bound_func
  25.                 return func(self, *args2, **kwargs2)
File "/home/ryuu/Programming/Python/tabr/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  95.                     result = middleware.process_view(request, view_func, args, kwargs)
File "/home/ryuu/Programming/Python/tabr/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/middleware/csrf.py" in process_view
  111.                 request.COOKIES[settings.CSRF_COOKIE_NAME])

Exception Type: AttributeError at /login/validate/
Exception Value: 'LoginView' object has no attribute 'COOKIES'
```

Comment: As Thomas answered, you can't decorate methods, check django-braces on how to achieve similar behavior in Class Based Views.

Comment: Will do! Recently ran into the decorators, so there are some fun stuff to read up on.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You used functions decorators on a method.

This won't work: the function as returned by the decorator expects its first argument to be a `request`, and receives `self` instead.

Use:

```
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator

csrf_protected_method = method_decorator(csrf_protect)
# and so on
```

Check [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/class-based-views/intro/#id1) for more details.

Comment: Thank you, it worked out great and the documentation will come in handy.

Comment: the relevant import for the method_decorator is `from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator`

Comment: The link is broken

Comment: Doc is old and I can't edit now. The new docs are in:  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/class-based-views/intro/